# using [ngClass] on Material Design table row

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Design table as follows. I would like to add a certain class to rows depending on the value of the relationship column. With a standard HTML table I could add a 'dependent' class to these rows as such:

```
<tr [ngClass]="{'dependent': element.relationship !== 'Primary'}"
```

How can I do this with my material table?

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="employeeDisplayList" class="mat-elevation-z8 table">

<!-- Employee Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="employeeName">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Employee Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.employeeName}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Relationship Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="relationship">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Relationship </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.relationship}} </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do so from html for `mat-table`. Instead, you can set the class on the `td` or `th` element.

Answer (score -2):

Try like this

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'dependent': element.relationship !== 'Primary'}"></tr>
```